# Cloud9 and Jade

Tags: pug, cloud9-ide

Looking around Google I can see a few people have asked this but there is no real response. Does Cloud9 IDE have support for Jade? If so do I have to turn it on or something, if not is it in the pipeline?

I think some clarification would greatly help myself and any others. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [currently a feature request](http://cloud9ide.zendesk.com/entries/21201847-support-for-jade-and-maybe-stylus-would-be-nice) and is not in the current Cloud9 IDE.  To try and get it faster, you can always [upvote](http://cloud9ide.zendesk.com/entries/21201847-support-for-jade-and-maybe-stylus-would-be-nice) the request to get more attention (I just did, because that'd be sweet to have it recognize Jade).

### Update - Cloud9 now supports Jade!

Comment: Anytime!  I hope they add it soon.